Double integral of $\iint x\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ using polar coordinates
Solve$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm d}$
$$\iint_D x\,\dd x\,\dd y$$
using $x= 2r \cos \phi, y= r \sin \phi$ over D: $x^2+4y^2 \leq 4, x \geq 0$.
I obtain $r \leq 1$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2} \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ since $x \geq 0$. I perform the following calculations
$$
\begin{align*}
\iint_E 2r \cos (\phi)\, r \,\dd r \,\dd\phi 
&= 2\int_{3\pi /2}^{\pi/2} \cos \phi\,\dd \phi \int_0^1 r^2\,\dd r\\
&= 2\int_{3\pi /2}^{\pi/2} \cos \phi\,\dd\phi \bigg[ \frac{r^3}{3} \bigg]_0^1\\
&= \frac{2}{3}\int_{3\pi /2}^{\pi/2} \cos \phi\,\dd\phi\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \left[ \sin \phi \right]_{3\pi /2}^{\pi/2}\\
&= \frac{4}{3} \neq \frac{8}{3} = \mathrm{answer}
\end{align*}$$
Any suggestions on what I missed?

Since $x=2r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$, the absolute value of the Jacobian of this change of variable is $2r$. Therefore, you should have computed$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^1\color{red}4r^2\cos(\phi)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\phi.$$

Thanks. It does not matter if I use $-\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$ in the integral?

I think that it is weird, to say the least. Note that $\frac{3\pi}2>\frac\pi2$, and that therefore there is no $\phi$ such that $\frac{3\pi}2\leqslant\phi\leqslant\frac\pi2$.

I see ... thanks!
